# How to track the scroll from the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to track the scroll from the top of the page in order to add a class to the header. Now my code does not work and the class is not added. How can I solve this problem?

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');

body.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let scrollTop = body.scrollHeight;

  let headerWrapper = document.querySelector('.header');

  if (scrollTop >= 100) {
    headerWrapper.classList.add('hide');
  } else {
    headerWrapper.classList.remove('hide');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the `scrollY` property of the `window` object, rather than working with properties of the body.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let headerWrapper = document.querySelector('.header');

  if (window.scrollY >= 100) {
    headerWrapper.classList.add('hide');
  } else {
    headerWrapper.classList.remove('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #CCC;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="header">Text</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Text again

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
And more text

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Also way down here

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
The end
```

**EDIT**

The scroll event listener needs to also be on the `window`, not the body.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, your code does not add a class to the header when scrolling.

Comment: @stas333 That was a small oversight on my part. The event listener needs to be attached to the `document` or `window`, not the body. Attaching it to the body never triggers the event as the scroll occurs on the document and window. The snippet has been updated.